# Extract object from black background OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, image-segmentation

First you have to know that I work with OpenCV in C++ in Visual Studio.

I have a picture like : [Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLk0U.png)

I want to create a new picture of the hand but with a lot less of black bacground.
So the final image should look like this : [Final Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfP08.png)

I know there are some OpenCv functions that could help me but I have really trouble to implement the algorithm because OpenCv can't be used in Debug Mode so it hard to check what  I am doing.

Have anyone any idea how to proceed ?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: A Canny Edge detector method using to find the edge, after can you crop the image. (OR) You need to find convex hull http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html  i hope the above links are helpful to you

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer !  In my case, finding bouding  rectangle is better but this method is also really good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find contour, find bounding rectangle, crop.

Here is example of finding bounding box: [example](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I need. 
Have a good day ! :)